# How to prove ${2n \choose n} = 2\cdot (2n-1) \cdot \frac{1}{n} {2(n-1) \choose n-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I've been staring at this identity which appears in my textbook for a while. Plugging in numbers I can verify that this is true, however I have no idea how this was determined or proved? Is there a nice result about binomial coefficients that gives this identity?

The only thing that comes to mind is a creative application of Pascal's identity, but even then I'm getting the result.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the binomials with factorials and using induction?

Comment: I have although nothing particularly cancels out. Not sure why I would need induction.

Comment: @GraphMathTutor Do you know how to express binomial coefficients via factorials?

Comment: Yes, that is something I am comfortable with. I've reduced the RHS to $\frac{2\cdot (2n-1)!}{n!(n-1)!}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2(2n-1)\frac1n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}=\frac{(2n)(2n-1)}{n^2}\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!}
=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\binom{2n}n.$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\displaystyle{a \choose b} = \frac{a \cdot (a-1) \cdots (a-b+1)}{b!}$

The denominator of $\displaystyle{2n \choose n}$ is $n!$.
The denominator of $\displaystyle{2(n-1) \choose n-1}$ is $(n-1)!$.
So $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n} {2(n-1) \choose n-1}$ has the same denominator as ${2n \choose n}$.

The numerator of $\displaystyle{2n \choose n}$ is $2n\cdots (n+1)$.
The numerator of $\displaystyle{2(n-1) \choose n-1}$ is $(2n-2)\cdots n$.
So $\displaystyle\frac{(2n)(2n-1)}{n}{2(n-1) \choose n-1}$ has the same numerator as ${2n \choose n}$.

Comment: I believe the denominator of ${2n\choose n}$ is $(n!)^2$, not just $n!$

Comment: @GraphMathTutor, I meant in the form given in first sentence.